# Flex direction elements width

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I do not know why by setting flex-direction to column my elements inside get width to 100%? I just want to make it vertical direction, but not wider. Can I do it without wrapping element in additional div? Please look at example below:

```
<button class="button">Good width</button>
<div class="flex-content">
  <button class="button">Wrong width</button>
</div>

.button {
  height: 36px;
}

.flex-content {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QzGQQm

Regards

Comment: add `align-items:flex-start`

Comment: but now they are not centered

Comment: You can add `align-self: center;` to the button element to centre it within its parent.

Comment: I gave you a fast fix but you have to do a little effort reading the doc of the property and the duplicate then you will be able to do what you want. Don't simply wait to get a working code to simply copy paste